# ImportError: No module named gdata.youtube.service in Django windows 7

Tags: django, youtube-api

After installing `django-youtube` while running `manage.py syncdb`

```
ImportError: No module named gdata.youtube.service
```

this error is showed. Any suggestion?

Comment: in your python console, or django shell, try `import gdata.youtube.service` and see what happens

Comment: same reply no module name

Comment: how can add the missing library kindly can you plz write down the steps here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the dependencies library: [`gdata python library`](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list)

Documentation here:

- https://github.com/laplacesdemon/django-youtube#dependencies

And here is documentation on how to install python libraries

- http://docs.python.org/2/install/#installing-python-modules

Comment: from this link (http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list) I have to download all of them?